Does Uncanny Dodge mean 'never being surprised?'
I'm trying to understand how to make sense of Uncanny Dodge. In the pathfinder 1e ruleset, Uncanny Dodge does the following:

Starting at 4th level, a rogue can react to danger before her senses
would normally allow her to do so. She cannot be caught flat-footed,
nor does she lose her Dex bonus to AC if the attacker is invisible.
She still loses her Dexterity bonus to AC if immobilized. A rogue with
this ability can still lose her Dexterity bonus to AC if an opponent
successfully uses the feint action (see Combat) against her.

So Generally, surprise rounds do exactly that, you are considered flat footed. But what about assassinations? I get that there is a clause that states rogues 4 levels higher than than a person with Improved Uncanny Dodge can bypass this, but what about normal Uncanny Dodge? Does this mean that if a CR5 creature tries to surprise a 4th level rogue with Uncanny Dodge, it works? Because there is no '4 levels higher clause?'
Furthermore, what about abilities that specifically target unaware or flanked opponents? Such as this:

Deathstrike (Ex): Once per day, the Scorn Assassin can attempt to kill
a foe with a carefully placed blow. If the Scorn Assassin successfully
hits a target with a sneak attack, the target must make a
Fortitude save or be paralyzed for 1d4 rounds. This can only be used
when the target is unaware of the Scorn Assassin’s presence or is
flanked.

Realistically, Uncanny Dodge (even the improved version) doesn't make you immediately aware of anyone and everyone around you, does it? Wouldn't Deathstrike bypass Uncanny Dodge and Improved Uncanny Dodge?

I think the relevant part of uncanny dodge is:

She cannot be caught flat-footed, nor does she lose her Dex bonus to
AC if the attacker is invisible.

This explicitly states that it works even on an invisible attacker. It also explicitly states you can't lose dex bonus to AC or be caught flat-footed.
Now let's look at sneak attack:

The rogue’s attack deals extra damage anytime her target would be
denied a Dexterity bonus to AC (whether the target actually has a
Dexterity bonus or not), or when the rogue flanks her target.

So yes, uncanny dodge works even if you are completly unaware of the target. Sneak attack only works against you if you are flanked. Note that technically this does not mean you weren't surprised, just that mechanically you don't take the downside of being surprised. You can fail your perception, someone can sneak up on you and attack you, but you still keep your dex bonus to AC and are not considered flat-footed.
As for Deathstrike, it specifically states it applies when it successfully sneak attacks an opponent, therefore it can never apply to someone with uncanny dodge, unless that person is flanked.
These are the Rules as written (RAW), and the rules as intended (RAI). It is meant to be like a sixth sense; you are so used to exploring dangerous places you know you are about to be attacked as it happens at the last second, even if the person completly snuck up on you (you hear the swordswinging at the back of your head, or the person's footstep as they close the final distance, or feel the air their movement or the movement of their weapon makes and react at the last second to defend yourself as well as if you were always aware of the target).
Yes, it is a powerful ability (although very situational) which is why it's locked behind specific classes. Mostly notably the rogue, who it makes sense to have this ability as learning to sneak up on people also helps you recognize others sneaking up on you, as well as the barbarian and a few others. It is usually a few levels in so you can't just dip one level for it.

Yea, This is a fair assessment. Thanks for clarifying

First of all, "Realistically" generally doesn't apply to rules. Trying to stick to the text is the easiest way to go, unless it's really unconsistent with other things.
The CR of the creature should not compare to a character level. A creature can have class level or not.
Uncanny dodge reduce a lot a way to be surprised and lose his dext bonus, and thus, a lot of way to trigger a sneak attack on the rogue.
Regarding  Deathstrike, it will work if the Rogue is flanked, since Uncanny Dodge doesn't specify anything regarding this.

So. Despite, say for example, being in complete and utter darkness, with no way to see more than a few inches in front of you. Read as Written, a rogue with Uncanny Dodge just knows when they are about to be stabbed in the back by anyone, let alone a creature made of the darkness? That seems incredibly powerful

@APython I'd go as far as to say the ability to dodge a backstab in darkness like that is uncanny.

As far as power goes, it basically means that out of the two "squishiest" party members, the one who commonly scouts ahead solo is less likely to be instantly obliterated in a single attack. Since the Rogue is the most likely culprit if anyone else in the group suffers a "true" sneak attack (not just "you're flanked so I add damage")...
